# Solving Lagrangian (4 vars to solve for)

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I'm a bit new to Mathematica, but here's what I've got:

```
F[x_, w_, q_, s_] := x^a w^(1 - a) + q^a s^(1 - a)
G[x_, w_, q_, s_] := y - (1 + t) x + w + (((1 + k) q + s)/(1 + r))
gradf = {D[F[x, w, q, s], x], D[F[x, w, q, s], w], D[F[x, w, q, s], q], D[F[x, w, q, s], s]};
gradg = {D[G[x, w, q, s], x], D[G[x, w, q, s], w], D[G[x, w, q, s], q], D[G[x, w, q, s], s]};
Solve[{gradf == lambda gradg, G[x, w, q, s] == 0}, {x, w, q, s, lambda}]
```

It goes well until the last step, where it gives me the error "Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables," suggesting I'm solving for more variables than equations. But this isn't true (asfaik). There are 4 eqs from each element of the gradients matching the corresponding elements, plus the constraint. So 5 eq and 5 vars. Any thoughts?

Edit: Now the code is giving no solutions. However, the exact same code at one point gave this solution: 
[image]

Comment: I get no solution at all from your code. Make sure you clear all variables, maybe quit and restart.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Jens -- Strange, it gives no solutions when I rerun it now. But it did at one point. I edited the question with what it gave the one time it actually did give solutions.

Comment: I get this [these errors and a result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IwFj6.png) (for code form use: `Import["http://goo.gl/NaH6rM"]["http://i.stack.imgur.com/XCxVH.png"`), if I leave out the `g==0`-requirement.

Comment: I'm struggling to recreate that. I still get just {} for output, even leaving out the constraint and using the import line.

Comment: What are `a, t, k`, and `r`?